# Reason SPA pages are refreshing?

Tags: vue.js, single-page-application

Just finished learning `Vuejs` and after visiting a few websites that use `Vuejs` like;

```
a) https://coderstape.com
b) https://www.thenetninja.co.uk
c) https://laracasts.com
```

I noticed that by navigating around the websites we by clicking on `navbar` links and some other links then the pages refresh and I haven't been able to find out the reason online. Could someone kindly explain what's happening in that? Doesn't it go against the purpose of SPA?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For example the last site you specified: https://laracasts.com.

On its main page there is a white button "BROWSE COURSES". If you open Chrome DevTools panel(look at the picture with explanations), go to tab "Networks" (1) and then click on this white button, you can see GET request to "series?curated" (2). If you open its details, you can see that as response, new page is received in the form of an HTML code (3), not JSON for example, as is usually the case in SPA.

[image]

Also, if you look at what programming language is used on this site, for example, using service https://whatcms.org/?s=laracasts.com, you can see that this is a PHP, namely Laravel.

From all this, I can make the assumption that they use Vue.js only partially, maybe in several components, but the site navigation itself is presented in the form of traditional static pages, which is why the page reloads.

Also, for example, if you take a look at this website https://www.spendesk.com/, you can see that they use Vue.js+Nuxt.js, as well as Node.js, as indicated by service whatcms.org, and if you try to navigate to various pages on this site, you will see no page loading. I can say that this site is a true SPA in the form in which you mean it.

I heard that you can do a SPA with a Laravel backend, but I think that's another story.

Comment: thanks, this sheds some light.

Before we get to laravel and SPA maybe you may know something that might help as I'm just getting started with programming.

 I went to the https://www.spendesk.com/ website and navigated to it's various pages and most of them do not refresh, but if you navigate to resources->blog, resources->partnership->become a partner and  resources->help centre then you'll notice the pages refresh. I'm wondering what factor is considered when deciding a page to be static or not! 

What pages to  use Vue.js and what pages not to

Comment: @AlphyGacheru As you may have noticed, all the examples you indicated where the page is reloaded are not part of the main site(application), but are located on the subdomains of this site. Therefore, instead of using routing(vue-router), which you should know is used in the SPA, it seems to me that for these links they just used HTML’s anchor tag ```<a>``` or JavaScript’s window.location or window.open etc. to change the subdomain. Also if you inspect those subdomains with whatcms.org, you will notice changes in the technologies used, so these subdomains can already be called separate sites.

Comment: Helpful, I'm getting myself into laravel and Vue.js. Done a few projects with Laravel only... any advice in your experience now that you mentioned SPA with laravel backend?

Comment: @AlphyGacheru Honestly, I am far from the area of PHP and its frameworks, but as I understand, having searched a little in Google, Laravel and Vue are best used together in the following situations:
#1.the dynamics on the page, i.e. even a simple "if field A has changed, then change field B" is much easier and faster than in jquery / javascript
#2. templating. For example, you need to make a convenient template in JS - you can either invent the engine itself, or use ready-made, Vue is one of them.

Comment: @AlphyGacheru #3. Displaying data from the server. Again, you can generate the entire html on the server or you can generate it on the client. The server has its own pros and cons, the client has its own.
The convenience of VUE is that it can be used on individual elements of individual pages. There is no need to completely switch to it for all pages. This by the way is shown by the sites you indicated from the description of the original question.

Comment: #4 Write a dynamic frontend using Vue, Angular, React or whatever. The backend sends you notifications via websockets about new data without reloading the page. Hope this helps :)